# Python script won't run on PHP

Tags: python, serial, arduino, server, php

My goal is to write a string through the serial of my Raspberry Pi which will then be sent towards an Arduino and I'll read it through the Serial Monitor.

I got my Python script working and it works perfectly when I execute it on the Raspberry Pi's terminal. As soon as I run it through the website, it does not work.

To test it out, I made the PHP code run the script as soon as the site was launched. This is what the code looks like:

```
<?php

    exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/UART3.py test');

?>
```

The test at the end of the exec() sends that string through the serial communication. I can copy and paste that code into the terminal and it works perfectly.

Things I have done:

- Tested the code individually (works)
- Gave rights to www-data by doing `chmod +x UART3.py`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you execute anything from the `exec` function?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l UART3.py`?

Comment: @yambo1 the `ls -l UART3.py` reads `-rwxr-xr-x`. And yes I normally can execute things with exec function. Just now i redid my entire code in C, compiled it, and ran that through through the website using the same `exec` function and it works perfect. Now I'm curious as to why it worked when I did it with the C compiled file as opposed to the python file.

Comment: What is the output of `echo exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/UART3.py test');` in your php file

Comment: @yamboy1 it doesn't output anything. The php is the in the header of my HTML file. If i put `echo exec( 'chmod +x' )` it doesn't change anything or show anything on the website. Am i supposed to type that into a specific program? Just to be clear, I'm doing all of this headless on my Raspberry Pi Rasbian Jessie and then checking the results out via website and Arduino serial monitor

Comment: Try my new comment. I posted the wrong command in that other one

Comment: Same issue. Nothing happened. I gave the file permission to be ran, its the right pathway, and the python code does work. I can't think of any other reason as to why it won't execute with PHP

Comment: I think this might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51471/67191

Comment: that worked. Thank you so much. So the issue was the device itself not having the privilege. Which is weird because the C code worked completely fine without having to `chmod 777 dev/ttyAMA0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found thanks to @yamboy1 and finding this link: [How to set a permission to call a Python script from PHP?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51471/67191)

Basically, I had to give the correct privilege to the device itself. Instead of doing `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0` like @Diego Dyan did, i did `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyAMA0`

So for people in the future, things to check:

- Does your program work individually? Compile it and run it by itself to check.
- Does your file have the correct privilege? In my case, the python code. If not, do `sudo chmod +x file.py`
- Does your device have the correct privilege? If not, do `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyAMA0`

Comment: Nice summary. However, it doesn't explain why your c code worked but the python version didn't. How did the c code access the device without the permissions set correctly?

Comment: @DaddytheRunner , that I couldn't figure out. If anyone would like to spread the knowledge, please do.